# Java: why char1|=char2 is not equal to char1=char1|char2?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, char

For example, we have

```
char char1 = 0, char2 = 0;
```

This works fine:

```
char1 |= char2;
```

This does not:

```
char1 = char1 | char2;
```

The latter leads to "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char"

Why these options have different behavior?

Where "int" has emerged? According to Oracle:

- bitwise operators "can be applied to any of the integral types"
- char is an integral type

Comment: Interesting question. Why do you want this, what are you trying to obtain? The short answer is that the funny and unexpected behaviour is taken over from C and C++

Comment: I am afraid you over-interpreted [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). It says that bitwise operators can be applied to integral types and that `~` (complement) *can be applied to any of the integral types*. Easy to misunderstand. What it does not say is that using `|` (or) on `char` first promotes the operands to `int`. Yeah, it’s confusing.

Comment: Thank you all! I have found [the complete answer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). From now on I will carefully read the tutorial: "perform bitwise and bit shift operations on integral types" does not mean that it preserves that types.